# How to change the language, for just a few lines in a template?

Tags: bibliographies, templates, languages, thesis

I am using a Persian (thesis) template and in the references, there is a problem. In fact, some of them, contain a formula and since the template considers the numbers in the context of a Persian master, the numbers in these references are in Persian, and the rest of these titles are in English. Is there any environment to solve this problem and change the numbers style to English?
The template can be found [here.](http://www.parsilatex.com/joomla/index.php/remository/Thesis_Templates/%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%DB%8C%D9%84-%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA%DA%A9-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%BE%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%86%E2%80%8C%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B4%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%AA%D8%A7-%D8%AF%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%B4%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85-%D9%88-%D8%B5%D9%86%D8%B9%D8%AA-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86/)

```
@article{romeo2011effective,
  title={The effective stability parameter for two-component galactic discs: is 
  {$Q^{-1}\sim Q^{-1}_{\text{stars}}+Q^{-1}_{\text{gas}}$}?},
  author={Romeo, Alessandro B and Wiegert, Joachim},
  journal={Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society},
  volume={416},
  number={2},
  pages={1191--1196},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}
```

[image: This is the mentioned reference.]

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal example that produces that bib entry (and its erroneous output), and also include relevant packages that you are loading.

Comment: use package `biblatex` and define the `langid` field in the bibliography entry.

Comment: @Herbert: Tnx. can U plz bring an example?

Comment: Your template uses the old BibTeX format. I cannot test it with `biblatex`, too many problems with package `xepersian`.